# 2008 R2 DNS Won't Start or Stay Running

Tags: server, windows-server-2008

I am dealing with a situation where I am unable to get DNS started and to stay running.
I am moving from 2003 r2 to 2008 r2 (I know we are behind, but had legacy issues). We recently had another DC machine go down where we had AD, DHCP, and DNS that we had to use meta cleanup on. 
The only weird thing is that I still see that old machine showing up in the DNS plugin...with a red x.
Anyway, I performed all of the necessary steps to prepare the domain and brought a 2008r2 machine online and is now am DC. However, when I try to start the DNS service on this machine it fails.
I did some research and I do not have KB4019264 or KB3145126 installed.
The Application logs give the following error:
Faulting application name: dns.exe, version: 6.1.7601.23764, time stamp: 0x58e7aa3d
Faulting module name: dns.exe, version: 6.1.7601.23764, time stamp: 0x58e7aa3d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000061393
Faulting process id: 0x378
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ec70619ab7e6
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\dns.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\dns.exe
Report Id: a0543e98-5863-11e7-9745-000c295aff53
I am really at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am open to any trouble shooting suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, however, i did not have (KB4019264) installed individually.  Or, more like, it was installed as part of a rollup I assume since (KB4019264) was part of (KB4014504).  I uninstalled (KB4014504) and was still not able to start DNS.  I saw Kixtart post and noticed i had(KB4022719) installed.  After I removed that update and rebooted, DNS started on my 2008R2 DC's.  Much thanks everyone.. this was also driving me crazy

Link:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fe692fec-a14e-44c6-92fa-6863bf4550da/kb4019264-causes-dns-service-to-not-start?forum=winservergen